# Python 3.10.2 - printing a list for objects in classes as method

Tags: python, list, class, methods, printing

Started learning objects and have problem with printing as method.

```
import random

class Animal(object):
    
    def __init__(self, race, name, hunger, boredom):
        race = input("Animals race: ")
        name = input("Animals name: ")
        hunger = random.randrange(0, 6)
        boredom = random.randrange(0, 6)
        self.race = race
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom
        
def main():
    animals = []
    animals.append(Animal(None, None, None, None))
    animals.append(Animal(None, None, None, None))

    for i in animals:
        print("\n", i.race, "named", i.name, "\n\n",
              "Status:\n",
              "Hunger:", i.hunger, "\n",
              "Boredom:", i.boredom, "\n")

main()

input("To exit press enter")
```

I would want to replace `for` loop in `main()` by just a simple `print(animals)`.

Tried as `__str__()`

```
    def __str__(self):
        rep = "\n" + self.race + "named" + self.name +"\n\n",
        rep += "Status:\n"
        rep += "Hunger:" + str(self.hunger) + "\n"
        rep += "Boredom:" + str(self.boredom) + "\n"
        return rep
```

but it's generating me following error:
`[<__main__.Animal object at 0x000001521C48AD40>, <__main__.Animal object at 0x000001521C48AC80>]`

Found and answer with `__repr()__`:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

which says:
`TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`

and here my ideas how to fix it ends.

Comment: Look for errant commas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a comma at the end of this line

```
    rep = "\n" + self.race + "named" + self.name +"\n\n",
```

making it seem like `rep` is a tuple.

Comment: Ok, now I feel kinda ashamed -.-' methodology was fine, but focus after copy paste failed. Thanks! However... I found a new thing